# How to parse and simplify a string like '3cm/µs² + 4e-4 sqmiles/km/h**2' treating physical units correctly?

Tags: python, parsing, sympy

I'd like to split a string like `3cm/µs² + 4e-4 sqmiles/km/h**2` into its [SI unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (in this case, `m/s**2`) and its magnitude (in multiples of that unit).

Since sympy provides both a [parsing module](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html) and [many physical units and SI prefixes](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/physics/units.html), I guess using sympy would be a good idea. But what is a nice way to achieve this? I'd write an algorithm like the following, but I'd like to avoid reinventing a squared wheel:

- Treat the transition between a number and a letter (except for the `4e-4` like syntax) and whitespace (unless its next to an explicit operator) as multiplication, then tokenize
- Replace each non-numeric token by its SI representation (also checking for SI-prefixes)
- Simplify the new expression down to `Magnitude * some SI units` (giving a meaningful error message on inconsistent units, e.g. `Cannot add m**2 to s`)

Can this be easily achieved via existing means? Or how would this be best implemented?

Comment: Are you allowing free text input?  If not, one way to short circuit this issue is to create the parsing information as they enter data (eg if this was for an app with a 'cm' button, add an appropriate object then).  Otherwise, your approach sounds ok.  I'd do units first, then magnitude replacements, then just exec the math.

Comment: @sapi Yes, it's free text input, e.g. via a configuration text file. Otherwise a text field plus e.g. a pull-down unit menu would simplify this a lot indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Units

A solution would be to gather all units from the SymPy `units` module and use them to substitute the symbols created by `sympify`

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u 
... subs = {} 
... for k, v in u.__dict__.items(): 
...     if isinstance(v, Expr) and v.has(u.Unit): 
...         subs[Symbol(k)] = v # Map the `Symbol` for a unit to the unit

>>> # sympify returns `Symbol`s, `subs` maps them to `Unit`s
>>> print sympify('yard*millimeter/ly').subs(subs)
127*m/1313990343414000000000
```

If the symbol is not in `units` it will just be printed as unknown symbol (for instance `barn`)

```
>>> print sympify('barn/meter**2').subs(subs)
barn/m**2
```

But you can always add stuff to the `subs` dictionary.

```
>>> subs[Symbol('almost_meter')] = 0.9*u.meter
... sympify('almost_meter').subs(subs)
0.9*m
```

SI prefixes don't work exactly like you want them. You will need to add a multiplication sign (or hope that it is a common unit like `km` which is explicitly implemented). Moreover, as they are not `Unit` instances but rather `Integer` instance you will have to add them to `subs`:

```
>>> import sympy.physics.units as u
... subs = {} 
... for k, v in u.__dict__.items(): 
...     if (isinstance(v, Expr) and v.has(u.Unit)) or isinstance(v, Integer): 
...         subs[Symbol(k)] = v 

>>> print sympify('mega*m').subs(subs)
1000000*m
```

For unicode you might need some preprocessing. I do not think SymPy makes any promises about unicode support.

If you implement new `Unit`s, please consider making a pull request with them on github. The file to edit should be `sympy/physics/units.py`.

### Whitespaces and implicit multiplication

In the dev version of SymPy you can find code for assuming implicit multiplications where appropriate whitespaces are written:

```
>>> from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (parse_expr,
... standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application)

>>> parse_expr("10sin**2 x**2 + 3xyz + tan theta",
...            transformations=(standard_transformations + 
...                             (implicit_multiplication_application,)))
3*x*y*z + 10*sin(x**2)**2 + tan(theta)
```

### Security

`sympify` uses `eval` which is exploitable if you are going to use it for a web facing app!

Comment: I guess we ought to document that for `sympify`.

Comment: At what point does `sympify` use `eval` (also @asmeurer) - indirectly via `parse_expr`? One could also argue about [`return a._simpy_()`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/core/sympify.py#L239), if someone manages to sneak in a class with such a method.

Comment: `parse_expr` works by adding tokens using an extension of the `tokenize` module, and then evaling the resulting string.

Comment: Actually this does not work (at least not in 2018). Trying to do something like `sympify('m/s').subs(subs)` will fail, because `m` is first substituted by `meter` and then it fails, trying to substitute `meter` by `meter`. An updated answer which works would deserve a +1. I would also recommend to improve this answer by importing all quantities used (e.g. sympify, Symbol, etc.) and replacing `print something` (python 2) with `print(something)` (python 3) so it becomes a valid MWE.

Comment: Parsing to sympy.physics.units is a nightmare, to import text containing quantities I ended up using pint module and then converting pint quantities to sympy quantities with https://github.com/hgrecco/pint/issues/606#issuecomment-1771719687

Answer (score 3):

I've found [astropy](https://github.com/astropy/astropy/blob/master/astropy/units/tests/test_units.py) to have a good units module. After some preparation you can do

```
import astropy.units as u
from functools import reduce
u.Unit('MeV/fm').si #160.218 N
eval('1*MeV/fm+3*N',u.__dict__).si #163.21765649999998 N

from astropy.units import imperial
u.__dict__.update(imperial.__dict__)
u.sqmiles = u.mile**2
eval('3*cm/Ys**2 + 4e-4*sqmiles/km/h**2',u.__dict__).si #7.993790464000001e-08 m / s2
```

The following function adds `scipy` CODATA constants as quantities to `astropy` units

```
def units_and_constants():
    """
    >>> u = units_and_constants()
    >>> u.hartree_joule_relationship
    <Quantity 4.35974434e-18 J>

    >>> eval('1*MeV/fm+3*N',u.__dict__).si
    <Quantity 163.21765649999998 N>

    """
    import astropy.units as u
    from astropy.units import imperial
    u.__dict__.update(imperial.__dict__)
    from scipy.constants import physical_constants, value, unit
    import string
    def qntty(x): 
        un = unit(x)
        va = value(x)
        if un:
            return va*eval(un.strip().replace(' ','*').replace('^','**'),u.__dict__)
        else:
            return va
    u.sr = u.radian**2
    u.E_h = qntty('hartree-joule relationship')
    u.c = qntty('speed of light in vacuum')
    u.C_90 = (1+4.6e-8)*u.C 
    codata = {}
    for n, t in physical_constants.items():
        v = qntty(n)
        for x in string.punctuation+' ':
            n = n.replace(x,'_')
        codata[n] = v
    u.__dict__.update(codata)
    return u
```

[yt](http://yt-project.org/) also [tackles a problem similar to yours](http://ytep.readthedocs.org/en/latest/YTEPs/YTEP-0011.html).
Have a look at the [Test file](https://bitbucket.org/MatthewTurk/yt/src/f157266200b526c63adde4e67971c932a169c4bb/yt/utilities/tests/test_units.py?at=yt-3.0) to see how it is used.

Comment: Neat! I must have missed the notification, sorry for the late recognition