# How to pythonically tuple magnitude and physical units?

Tags: python, tuples

Now that the question of [how to parse a string for magnitude and physical unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895819/how-to-parse-and-simplify-a-string-like-3cm-s-4e-4-sqmiles-km-h2-treatin) is settled, the next question is, how should one best go on about packing these two together in a way that on the one hand does not cost too much performance but on the other hand adds a unit validation.

To make clear what I mean, take as an example two velocities `v = 5 m/s` and `u = 10 mph`. The [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15895819) already takes care of converting everything to [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (so you won't [crash another Mars mission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Climate_Orbiter#Cause_of_failure) due to *that*). So internally one would have e.g. a tuple `v = (5, m/s)` and `u = (4.4704, m/s)` and the output routine would take care of using the preferred units for output. While applying unit-compatible operations on the two, e.g. addition, or subtracting their squares, are valid, others like `v - 1/u` are complete and utter nonsense. But how should this best be implemented? Some possibilities that I considered so far:

- Don't. Since internally only SI units are used it *might* be obvious which units apply. But neglecting that information is very likely to become a source of bugs if the formulae become more complex
- Subclass `tuple` and override all valid operations prepending unit consistency checks. Sounds fun...
- Store the values as `sympy.core.mul.Mul`s of the magnitude times a (meaningful function of) `sympy.physics.unit.Unit`, e.g `v = 5*unit.m/unit.s`. I don't expect great performance of this, plus I'd still have to check whether the result of an operation is still of the form `magnitude * unit`.
- Use a `numpy.array` with an additional `sympy.physics.unit.Unit` entry, which already implements the elementwise operations. This would still require a manual unit consistency check afterwards (the fact that e.g. `m+m=2m` would also need to be treated...)
- Subclass `numpy.array` instead of `tuple`, override the operators prepending the unit consistency check *before* calling the `super`-operators on the array *without* the unit. Maybe some `__getattribute__` magic could simplify this since all valid operations are already implemented for both magnitude and unit...

Is one of these solutions good/pythonic? Or what other way is there? Does a library that treats this already exist?

**edit** Note that this should not be restricted to scalar values; vectors, matrices (maybe even `sympy.Symbol`s) should also work

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Magnitude](http://juanreyero.com/open/magnitude/) library:

```
from magnitude import mg

m = mg(5, 'kg')
a = mg(9.82, 'm/s2')
f = m * a
print f, f == mg(49.1, 'N')

u = mg(70, 'km/h')
g = mg(9.82, 'm/s2')
s = (u**2) / (2*g)
print s, s > mg(10, 'm')
```

The interesting thing happens when there is a unit mismatch:

```
>>> m = mg(5, 'kg')
>>> a = mg(9.82, 'm/s')
>>> f = m * a
>>> print f, f == mg(49.1, 'N')
MagnitudeError: Incompatible units in comparison: [1, -2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] and [1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Not the best error message perhaps, but it effectively prevents you from handling values in the wrong way.

Comment: Looks good (the error message is about the SI unit powers I guess). Can it also treat arrays?

Comment: Do you mean lists? `[mg(t, 's') * mg(70, 'km/h') for t in range(10)]`

Comment: I was thinking of vectors and matrices, e.g. 3D velocity vectors, and something like `mg([.5,0,3],'m/s')` would probably look nicer than `[mg(.5,'m/s'), mg(0,'m/s'), mg(3,'m/s')]`

Comment: Usually that is represented as a dimensionless unit vector and a magnitude.

Comment: Wouldn't that basically be using spherical coordinates? Addition wouldn't be too pleasant in that case...